# ¿Qué pasa si ofreces una recompensa y finalmente nadie la recibe? ¿Se devuelve la reputación?

Tags: soporte, recompensas

Pues eso, ¿qué pasa cuando ofreces una recompensa y finalmente, por no obtener una respuesta correcta, nadie se la recibe?

¿Se le devuelve al usuario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En el este [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) en el apartado -> ¿Cómo se concede una recompensa? esta lo que busca.

Breve resumen:

> ...Si no otorgas tu recompensa en 7 días (más el periodo de gracia),
>   la respuesta más votada publicada tras el ofrecimiento con una
>   puntuación mínima de 2 recibirá la mitad del importe de la
>   recompensa. Si hay dos respuestas o más que cumplan los criterios y
>   tengan la misma puntuación, la respuesta más antigua se llevará la
>   recompensa. Si no hay ninguna respuesta que cumpla los criterios, la
>   recompensa quedará sin otorgar...

Siempre puede consultar sus inquitudes en meta o donde corresponda y si no existe una pregunta al respecto, realizarla, pero quizas sea bueno que conozca la  seccion de sitio que se detalla a continuacion, quizas aprenda cosas que no sea preguntado aun.

Puede consultar otras cosas en el `Centro de Ayuda`, para acceder en el navbar (en la barra que esta arriba) en el boton `Ayuda -> Centro de ayuda`.

Comment: Gracias! Me queda claro

Comment: @UserNameYo No problem. Saludos

Comment: Cabe aclarar que, cualquiera sea el resultado, jamás se le devuelve al usuario.